# left and top margin appears after showing keyboard in WebView

Tags: keyboard, webview, cordova, margin

I have a web app in PhoneGap with a width and height of 100%, and it fills the whole page, but when I input or try to input a value(numeric) into a `<input>` field, a 2-3px wide margin appears on the top and to the right of the page. I even tried changing the margin of the `body` to -3px on all sides after, but still the white gap stays, it appears so far only in Android 2.2 and 2.3. Is it a bug, or am I the only one to have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this error on the app I'm working on. I am convinced this is a bug on Android 2.2 and above. I tried several possible solutions and found one that works. Unfortunately, I don't know why it works. It consists of three parts.

In the css file, I inserted the following:

```
#offset_wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: -20px;
}
```

Each time the app navigates to a page that contains elements with fixed position, we inserted the following code snippet:

```
$("div#main_container").append("<div id='offset_wrapper'>" + window.pageXOffset + "</div>");
```

Subsequently, every time the app navigates from these pages, the code below is applied.

```
$("#offset_wrapper").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with fixed position headers and footers. When navigating to the page where the inputs are, I changed the position css attribute for the header and footer to other than fixed and the body position to default(`css('position', '')`) in jQuery. When navigationg to the page where fixed position is needed I just changed it back.

Answer (score 0):

Old I know, but I fixed this or very similar issue in my phonegap application by specifying not the `left:0` on my fixed elements. Generally I kept only top or bottom specified for my 100% width fixed navigation header and footer elements.

When the keyboard flew out, about 5 pixels of margin would appear. Adding `left:0` stopped this from occurring for me.